# Error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Nanar_t’

Tags: c, function, struct, compiler-errors

here is my code, I think you will only need this piece:

```
struct Nanars{
    char* nom;
    int duree;
    int cote;
    int idClient;
}Nanar_t;
```

```
int trouverDureeMin(int nb, int a, Nanar_t* nana[nb]){
    int dureeMin=100;
    int indice=0;
    for(int j=0; j<nb; j++){
        if(j!=i){
            if(nana->duree[j]>nana->duree[a] && (nana->duree[j]-nana->duree[a])<dureeMin){
                indice=j;
                dureeMin=nana->duree[j]-nana->duree[a];
            }
            else if(nana->duree[j]<nana->duree[a] && (nana->duree[a]-nana->duree[j])<dureeMin){
                indice=j;
                dureeMin=nana->duree[a]-nana->duree[j];
        }
                    
    }
    return (j);
}
```

I have not tried a lot but I really can not figure out the problem. I have tried to name my variables differently though which does not make any difference.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build-log (copy-paste as text). And add comments in the code on the line where you get the error. If possible, also please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared an object with the name Nanar_t of the type struct Nanars

```
struct Nanars{
    char* nom;
    int duree;
    int cote;
    int idClient;
}Nanar_t;
```

So for example this funcitondeclaration

```
int trouverDureeMin(int nb, int a, Nanar_t* nana[nb]){
                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

is invalid.

It seems you mean to declare a typedef like

```
typedef struct Nanars{
    char* nom;
    int duree;
    int cote;
    int idClient;
}Nanar_t;
```

Also it is unclear where the variable `i` is declare

```
int trouverDureeMin(int nb, int a, Nanar_t* nana[nb]){
    int dureeMin=100;
    int indice=0;
    for(int j=0; j<nb; j++){
        if(j!=i){
        ^^^^^^^^
```

It seems you mean instead

```
        if(j!=a){
```

These if statements

```
        if(nana->duree[j]>nana->duree[a] && (nana->duree[j]-nana->duree[a])<dureeMin){
            indice=j;
            dureeMin=nana->duree[j]-nana->duree[a];
        }
        else if(nana->duree[j]<nana->duree[a] && (nana->duree[a]-nana->duree[j])<dureeMin){
            indice=j;
            dureeMin=nana->duree[a]-nana->duree[j];
    }
```

als0 do not make sense because the variable `nana` used in expressions like this `nana->duree[j]` has the type `Nanar_t**`. That is the pointer does not have the data member `duree`.

And returning j

```
return (j);
```

also does not make ense.

It seems you mean

```
return indice;
```

You need to rewrite the function anew. The provided code has too many bugs.